# Finitely generated ideals in a Principal Ideal Domain (PID)

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a PID every Ideal is Principal and hence an Ideal generated by a finite number of $n$ elements is the same as the Principal Ideal generated by the GCD of the $n$ elements. Is this result true in a Unique Factorization Domain (UFD)? In a UFD also the GCD of a finite number of $n$ elements exists but I am not sure if the GCD will generate the same Ideal generated by the $n$ elements. I will be thankful if anyone could point out the proof or a counter example for disproving the same.

Comment: How about the ring of polynomials over the integers?

Comment: Z[x] is a UFD. The ideal generated by <2,x> is not Principal. GCD of 2 and x is 1. Fine. I got the answer. 1 can not be written as 2a+xb for any a,b in Z[x]. Am I correct?